# Only one digit in char

Tags: c++, function, char

I programmed a function which shall only proceed if the input is "1" , "2", "3" or "4". So if I type 5 eg. It says "It's wrong, try again". 
My problem is, that, if I type eg. "12" it still proceedes and not only that, it puts the "1" into the first cin >> and the "2" into the next cin >> of my program. How can I tell him that also "12" is not right, but only "1, 2, 3, and 4"?

**This is my function**

```
char zeichen;


void operation()
{
    bool beginn = false;
    do
    {
        cout << "----- Geben Sie hier den Operator ein, mit welchem Sie rechnen wollen -----" << endl;
        cout << "___________________________________________________________________________" << endl << endl;
        cout << " | 1 | Addition" << endl;
        cout << " | 2 | Subtraktion" << endl;
        cout << " | 3 | Multiplikation" << endl;
        cout << " | 4 | Division; inklusive Rest" << endl;
        cout << "___________________________________________________________________________" << endl << endl << endl;

        cout << "Ihre Auswahl: ";
        cin >> zeichen;
        switch(zeichen)
        {
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
            beginn = true;

            break;

        default:
            cout << endl << "Ihre Angabe ist nicht richtig. Bitte geben Sie eine der gegebenen Ziffern ein." << endl << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            break;
        }
        system ("CLS");
    }
    while (beginn == false);
}
```

**And this is my main program where its called (Just a part of it)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conversions.h"
#include "rechnung.h"
#include "menue.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int rechnung()
{
    unsigned int basis;
    string eingabe1;
    string eingabe2;
    //unsigned int eingabe;
    //unsigned int rest = 0;
    char again = 'Y';
    while (again == 'Y')
    {
        operation();
        system ("CLS");
        cout << "Nun geben Sie die Basis des Zahlensystems ein, in welchem Sie rechnen möchten" << endl;
        cin >> basis;
        cout << endl << "Sie rechnen nun im " << basis << "er Zahlensystem" << endl << endl;
        system ("CLS");

        cout << "Geben Sie bitte Ihre zwei Zahlen ein, mit denen Sie rechnen möchten" << endl;
        cout << " 1. Zahl: ";
        cin >> eingabe1;
        cout << endl << "2. Zahl: ";
        cin >> eingabe2;
        cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest would be to use:

```
int zeichen;
```

and

```
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
```

`cin` will then read multiple characters and interpret the input as a number, not as a single char.

Edit: If you want to handle other inputs, then you should use a `std::string zeichen`. You'll ned to use `if`s instead of `switch`

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that `zeichen` is a char so you only get one character.
If you read it again it would give you the second character (in your example it would be 2).

So you can read a string, check if the length is 1 and then use the `zeichen[0]` character.

You can also replace it with a number (int, long, or any other number type you like). Then the input will be parsed as a number so you will get 12 like you seem to expect.

Comment: @Janny Yes. cin is not the best option for building nice interactive programs. It's usually good enough for toy examples and very simple things. If you expect strange inputs, then maybe use strings and check the `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always the same answer to these kind of input validation questions. Forget about what you want the data to be and just think about what the user types. Always the user just types text. So read the user input into a string, and only if the input is what you are expecting convert it to the data you want.

So in your case read the data as a string

```
 cout << "Ihre Auswahl: ";
 string input;
 cin >> input;
```

Check if is the input is what you want

```
if (input != "1" && input != "2" && input != "3" && input != "4")
{
    cout << endl << "Ihre Angabe ist nicht richtig. Bitte geben Sie eine der gegebenen Ziffern ein." << endl << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Only if the input is what you want, convert it to a char

```
else
{
    char zeichen = input[0];
    switch (zeichen)
    {
    case '1':
        ...
    case '2':
        ...
    case '3':
        ...
    case '4':
        ...
    }
}
```

Something like that anyway. Hopefully you get the idea, you cannot check if the input is correct by assuming that the user is going to enter something correct. The user could enter anything.

Comment: @Janny Pass it as an argument to the function you're calling.

Comment: @Janny Passing arguments is much preferable to using global variables. Just do this `some_function(zeichen)`, this mean that `zeichen` is being passed as a argument to `some_function`. You need to learn how to pass values to functions and return values from functions. Absolutely vital to know how to do that.

Comment: @Janny Well then you need to pass the variable as a parameter to the first function, so it can pass it on to the second. This is normal programming. Using global variables is a trap for the newbie programmer. They seem to be easier especially in a short program but they repidly get out of hand and you can no longer tell how different pieces of your code interact because everything is being done through global variables which are accessible to all parts of your code.